# How to send fixed string value as sms message?

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

I'm making an application where a fixed value of a string will be sent to a number as sms. I can send sms when the value is not fixed but when I try to send a string that has a fixed value, I cannot receive the sms.

```
EditText etNumber;
String spamMessage = "Congratulations! Your number just won 2,000,000 PESOS!! REF NO.: PH3413RN For claim, kindly email your name and occupation to:walakongmagawa@gmail.com";

  public void MyMessage() {

        String phoneNum = etNumber.getText().toString().trim();

        if (etNumber.getText().toString().equals("123456789")) {
            if (!etNumber.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, spamMessage, null, null);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Message has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter number or message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Number is incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
```

I expect the output of the value of "spamMessage" will be sent via sms.

Comment: What do you mean by value is not fixed ?

Comment: Please fix your if - else statement. If I read it correctly you're checking if the number is 123456789 and if it is true, why check the value again if it is empty when you already know that it has a value of 123456789?

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified code, hope it will work. If it doesn't let me know.

```
EditText etNumber;
String spamMessage = "Congratulations! Your number just won 2,000,000 PESOS!! REF NO.: PH3413RN For claim, kindly email your name and occupation to:walakongmagawa@gmail.com";

public void MyMessage() {

    String phoneNum = etNumber.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!etNumber.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        if (etNumber.getText().toString().equals("123456789")) {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, spamMessage, null, null);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Message has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Number is incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter number or message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

**Free suggestion:** It seems like you're almost reaching 160 chars in the message string. If it exceeds 160 chars You will need to use then **sendMultipartTextMessage** with pending intent. It is the safest way I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on sending sms recently , hope this will work for you too:

```
    void sendMessage(String phoneNumber){
       String messageToSend = "Hey whatsup";
       try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, messageToSend, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Message Sent",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(context,ex.getMessage().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```